# How can I normalize an image with the Keras ImageDataGenerator class?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, normalization, image-preprocessing

I'm training a network from a paper which says the following:

> "We resize all the images to (256, 256) and **normalize them by a mean and standard deviation of 0.5 across RGB channels** before passing them through the respective networks."

I'm using the **ImageDataGenerator** class followed by **flow_from_directory()** to get my images from a directory of training set images.

I can't figure out which combination of parameters I need to use in order to end up with each image having a mean of 0.5 and standard deviation of 0.5 across the pixels in each RGB channel.

My current implementation is as follows:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.0, samplewise_center=True, samplewise_std_normalization=True,validation_split=0.99)
train_gen = datagen.flow_from_directory(dir_name, classes=['image_train'], batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                       class_mode=None, subset="training")
```

It appears to be generating images with a mean of 0 and pixels range from -1.7 to 2.3.

**Is it possible to achieve input images with a mean and standard deviation of 0.5 across RGB channels scaled to a range of strictly 0 to 1 using the ImageDataGenerator class without implementing my own pre-processing code?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **really** want to avoid putting that into preprocessing (which would appear to me to be the easiest way - adding a `preprocessing_function` to the ImageDataGenerator) you can start your network with a Multiply and an Add layer, to scale (by 0.5, because your Std is now 1) and to shift (by 0.5, because your mean is now 0) - please be aware that both Multiply and Add layers require the arguments to be tensors of the same size, so see the [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Add) how to create arbitrary tensors.